# How does `if` not evaluate all its arguments?

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to learn and understand the Lisp programming language to a deep level. The function `+` evaluates its arguments in applicative order:

```
(+ 1 (+ 1 2))
```

`(+ 1 2)` will be evaluated and then `(+ 1 3)` will be evaluated, but the `if` function works differently:

```
(if (> 1 2) (not-defined 1 2) 1)
```

As the form `(not-defined 1 2)` isn't evaluated, the program doesn't break.

How can the same syntax lead to different argument evaluation? How is the `if` function defined so that its arguments aren't evaluated?

Comment: It would not make any sense to do so. Example: `(if (ask-user-should-i-quit) (quit) (continue))`. Should that quit, even though the user does not want to?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I agree de question title was misleading, but the last two questions of the body are my doubts

Comment: It is not the same syntax. It is `(if ...)`. A form with an `IF` in front. All other forms don't have an `IF` in front. Like there is an `if` syntax in Pascal/C/Java/..., Common Lisp has an `IF` syntax.
You ask by writing 'How is the `if` function...?'. `IF` is not a function. Check the documentation.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm new to Lisp and thought Lisp syntax always was` (function args...)`, clearly I was wrong and thanks to this question I learnt about special operators. Its dificult to find out this trivial stuff when you don't find the right terms to expess what you are looking for

Comment: You can use this as a reference: http://clqr.boundp.org
It shows the syntax.

Comment: And the "bible": [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm) is a [**special operator**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm), not an ordinary function.

This means that the normal rule that the `rest` elements in the [compound form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm) are evaluated before the function associated with the `first` element is invoked is **not** applicable (in that it is similar to [macro forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababb.htm)).

The way this is *implemented* in a compiler and/or an interpreter is that one looks at the compound form and decides what to do with it based on [its `first` element](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm):

- if it is a special operator, it does its special thing;
- if it is a [macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababb.htm), its macro-function gets the whole form;
- otherwise it is treated as a function - even if no function is defined.

Note that some special forms can be defined as macros expanding to other special forms, but some special forms must actually be present.

E.g., one can define `if` in terms of [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm):

```
(defmacro my-if (condition yes no) 
  `(cond (,condition ,yes)
         (t ,no)))
```

and vice versa (much more complicated - actually, `cond` *is* a macro, usually expanding into a sequence of `if`s).

PS. Note that the distinction between system-supplied macros and special operators, while *technically* crisp and clear (see [`special-operator-p`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_specia.htm) and [`macro-function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_macro_.htm)), is *ideologically* blurred [because](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababb.htm)

> An implementation is free to implement a Common Lisp special operator
>   as a macro. An implementation is free to implement any macro operator
>   as a special operator, but only if an equivalent definition of the
>   macro is also provided.

Comment: Thanks for making it crystal clear, as a newbie to LISP I expected that there would be a syntax difference between functions, special forms and macros.

Comment: It should be pointed out that `cond` is a macro that uses `if` in its expansion, so `my-if` will still use `if` when fully expanded.

Comment: @sepp2k Is that stated in the CL spec somewhere? Eg. If I make a CL with cond as the conditional and if as a macro, would it violate spec?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, the spec for [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) specifically says that it's a macro whereas the spec for [`if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm) calls it a special operator.

Comment: @Sylwester: ANSI CL spec explicitly permits implementing macros as special operators as long as a macroexpansion is also provided.

Answer (score 5):

Lisp syntax is regular, much more regular than other languages, but it's still not completely regular: for example in

```
(let ((x 0))
   x)
```

`let` is not the name of a function and `((x 0))` is not a bad form in which a list that is not a lambda form has been used in the first position.

There are quite a few "special cases" (still a lot less than other languages, of course) where the general rule of each list being a function call is not followed, and `if` is one of them. Common Lisp has quite a few "special forms" (because absolute minimality was not the point) but you can get away for example in a scheme dialect with just five of them: `if`, `progn`, `quote`, `lambda` and `set!` (or six if you want macros).

While the syntax of Lisp is not totally uniform the underlying **representation** of code is however quite uniform (just lists and atoms) and the uniformity and simplicity of representation is what facilitates metaprogramming (macros).

"Lisp has no syntax" is a statement with some truth in it, but so it's the statement "Lisp has two syntaxes": one syntax is what uses the `reader` to convert from character streams to s-expressions, another syntax is what uses the compiler/evaluator to convert from s-expressions to executable code.

It's also true that Lisp has no syntax because neither of those two levels is fixed. Differently from other programming languages you can customize both the first step (using reader macros) and the second step (using macros).

Comment: Have heard many times the *"Lisp has no syntax"* statement, but no one explains the special cases. Thanks for your analysis!

Answer (score 5):

[sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077729/1281433) answers this question well, but there are a few more general aspects that I think are worth mentioning.  As that answer and others have pointed out, `if`, is built into the language as a special operator, because it really is a kind of primitive.  Most importantly, `if` is *not* a function.

That said, the *functionality* of `if` can be achieved using just functions and normal function calling where all the arguments are evaluated.  Thus, conditionals can be implemented in the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), on which languages in the family are somewhat based, but which doesn't have a conditional operator.

In the lambda calculus, one can define true and false as functions of two arguments.  The arguments are presumed to be functions, and true calls the first of its arguments, and false calls the second.  (This is a slight variation of [Church booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_booleans) which simply *return* their first or second argument.)

```
 true = λ[x y].(x)
false = λ[x y].(y)
```

(This is obviously a departure from boolean values in Common Lisp, where `nil` is false and anything else is true.)  The benefit of this, though, is that we can use a boolean value to call one of two functions, depending on whether the boolean is true or false.  Consider the Common Lisp form:

```
(if some-condition
  then-part
  else-part)
```

If were were using the booleans as defined above, then evaluating `some-condition` will produce either `true` or `false`, and if we were to call that result with the arguments

```
(lambda () then-part)
(lambda () else-part)
```

then only one of those would be called, so only one of `then-part` and `else-part` would actually be evaluated.  In general, wrapping some forms up in a `lambda` is a good way to be able delay the evaluation of those forms.

The power of the Common Lisp macro system means that we could actually define an `if` macro using the types of booleans described above:

```
(defconstant true
  (lambda (x y)
    (declare (ignore y))
    (funcall x)))

(defconstant false
  (lambda (x y)
    (declare (ignore x))
    (funcall y)))

(defmacro new-if (test then &optional else)
  `(funcall ,test
            (lambda () ,then)
            (lambda () ,else)))
```

With these definitions, some code like this:

```
(new-if (member 'a '(1 2 3))
  (print "it's a member")
  (print "it's not a member"))))
```

expands to this:

```
(FUNCALL (MEMBER 'A '(1 2 3))                     ; assuming MEMBER were rewritten 
         (LAMBDA () (PRINT "it's a member"))      ; to return `true` or `false`
         (LAMBDA () (PRINT "it's not a member")))
```

In general, if there is some form and some of the arguments aren't getting evaluated, then the (`car` of the) form is either a Common Lisp special operator or a macro.  If you need to *write* a function where the arguments will be evaluated, but you want some *forms* not to be evaluated, you can wrap them up in `lambda` expressions and have your function call those anonymous functions conditionally.

This is a possible way to implement `if`, if you didn't already have it in the language.  Of course, modern computer hardware isn't based on a lambda calculus interpreter, but rather on CPUs that have test and jump instructions, so it's more efficient for the language to provide `if` a primitive and to compile down to the appropriate machine instructions.

Comment: @eliocs Glad it was interesting!  I hope it might somewhat useful.  While you probably wouldn't go and implement `if` on your own, one very easy, and less error-prone way to write macros that evaluate some code is to write the _functional_ version of the thing you want to do that takes a function as an argument, and then write a macro with a code body that expands to call to the functional version passing the body wrapped up in a lambda expression.  The possible implementation of `if` described here is sort of like that, but farther than usual.

Answer (score 4):

It would not make any sense to do so. Example: `(if (ask-user-should-i-quit) (quit) (continue))`. Should that quit, even though the user does not want to?

`IF` is not a function in Lisp. It is a special built-in operator. Lisp a several built-in special operators. See: [Special Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm#clspecialops). Those are not functions.

Comment: I understand **why** it works like that, but I couldn't get my head around **how** it worked.

Comment: @eliocs: just like it works in 99% of other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are not evaluated as for functions, because `if` is a *special operator*.  Special operators can be evaluated in any arbitrary way, that's why they're called special.

Consider e.g.

```
(if (not (= x 0))
    (/ y x))
```

If the division was always evaluated, there could be a division by zero error which obviously was not intended.

Answer (score 2):

If isn't a function, it's a special form. If you wanted to implement similar functionality yourself, you could do so by defining a macro rather than a function.

This answer applies to Common Lisp, but it'll probably the same for most other Lisps (though in some `if` may be a macro rather than a special form).

Comment: How would a macro `my-if` could be defined to work as the `if` special form?

Comment: @eliocs It would simply expand to the built-in `if` most likely. You could also define it in terms of `and` and `or`, `when`, `cond` or similar constructs, but those are themselves only macros that use `if` in their expansion. You can't define a `my-if` that does not directly or indirectly use `if` unless you use your own encoding of booleans (through lambdas for example). This is similar to how you can't define your own version of `+` without using the built-in `+` (again unless you use your own numeric type instead of the built-in one).