# lisp function that doesn't evaluate his arguments

Tags: lisp, operator-precedence

For my homework, I have a small List interpreter written in C with few functions already coded : `set`, `cons`, `car`, `cdr` and `quote`.

And I have to add 6 another functions of my choice. 3 with argument evaluation, and 3 without argument evaluation.
With evaluation, I choose : `eq`, `+` and `-1`, 
but I don't have any idea for the 3 next, what kind of Lisp function is useful without argument evaluation ?

Comment: In Common Lisp, all functions evaluate their arguments.  If arguments aren't to be evaluated, then you need a macro or special form that doesn't evaluate its arguments.

Comment: Perhaps you could implement `cond` which does not evaluate its arguments like a function. Maybe you could implement some other special forms for control flow. Maybe you could implement `defun`.

Comment: Why tag common-lisp? Are you making a dual namespace lisp? lexically scoped of dynamicly scoped? I would have decided on those two before deciding on which special forms to implement besides `if` which is a slam dunk.

Answer (score 4):

## The need for deferred evaluation

All arguments to lisp [*functions*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababc.htm) are always evaluated.

This is not the case 
for [*macros*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm)
and [*special operators*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababa.htm),
one of which, [`quote`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm),
you have already implemented.

The standard example when deferred evaluation is useful is:

```
(if (under-attack-p)
    (launch-missiles)
    (print "Peace!"))
```

I the arguments of [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) were evaluated,
then we would ...

1. check whether we are under attack
2. [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) `Peace!`
3. launch the missiles
4. if we were under attack, return `Peace!` (the value returned by
   `print`), otherwise return the value of `launch-missiles`

However, the *special operator* `if` evaluates its first argument and
decides which of the other two argument to evaluate based on that value.

See also [How does `if` not evaluate all its arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19077142/850781)

## My recommendation for implementation is:

- [`dolist`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm) -- iteration
- [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) -- conditional
- [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) or [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) --  bindings